# WPF - Other startup window

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a problem. I'm working on a project with several people. There was a login window that someone installed as the first window that starts aftter you run the application. (not the mainwindow). I deleted that window because we don't need that anymore. Now v-studio gives me an error:

```
System.IO.IOException: 'Cannot locate resource 'login.xaml'.'
```

What do I need to adjust so I can get another window to start first when I run the application (not the main window).

Comment: @mm8 Hero!! .~.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to replace the `StartupUri` in `App.xaml` with a valid `Uri` to an existing window:

```
<Application ... 
         StartupUri="MainWindow.xaml" />
```